# Cisco WAP321 dropping ARP packets

Tags: cisco, arp, access-point, dropped

At my office we have 4 WAP321 connected directly to a Cisco 891f router.

Randomly throughout the day, computers will lose access to the network. They will remain connected to the Wifi SSID, but can't ping any network resource. Not even the default gateway.
I have observed that when this issue happens, the computer (Windows 7/8/10) somehow drops the ARP entry for the default gateway. It then sends several ARP request broadcasts, which reach the router. The router replies (according to the debug logs at least) but the computer never gets those packets.
This lack of default gateway ARP entry can last for a few seconds, to about 45 minutes.

We have established the issue to be related to the access points. Connected them to a different router (some huawei 4G router) and the issue continued. When we connected a different AP to the cisco router (we re-purposed a TPLINK wifi router as an access point) no one has had the network connection loss.

I'm currently at a loss on what to do. The APs are upgraded to the latest firmware (1.0.6.2). They are mostly configured with the default settings (changed the SSIDs, radio channel and added them to a Single Point Setup cluster).

I can't force the issue to occur (don't know whats blocking the ARP replies, or even whats causing the computers to lose the default gateway configuration... It happened even when i was pinging the default gateway), and i can't find a way to find who it will happen to next.

I'm open to all ideas and suggestions on how to further diagnose this issue!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good question for networkengineering.stackexchange.com.

But:

I have resolved this exact bug in the past by enabling "Untagged Vlan" in the **VLAN and IPv4 Addresses** section under **LAN**.  Also set the untagged and mgmt vlans to the default of ID 1.

Yes, it sounds insane but it solved my problem with Cisco WAPs exhibiting the exact same behavior last year.  I dug this workaround up from a Cisco forum somewhere.